# show date in search results (drupal 10)

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-10

I have a site in Drupal version 10.2.2
When I search in Search

```
title
content
```

Lists the results in the form of a list.
I want to show the date information next to the title information.
Where and how can I do this?

I couldn't find the module that solves this job.
I guess it will be solved with twig?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can achieve this:

1. [Create a custom theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal) (if not already done)
2. Override the search result template by creating `search-result--node-search.html.twig` file in your custom theme's templates directory

```html
{{ title_prefix }}
<h3{{ title_attributes }}>
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ title }}</a>
</h3>
{{ title_suffix }}
{% if snippet %}
  <p{{ content_attributes }}>{{ snippet }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% if info %}
  <p>{{ info }}</p>
{% endif %}
<span class="search-result__date">{{ content['#node'].field_date.value|date('Y-m-d') }}</span>
```

3. [Clear the cache](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/prevent-cache-clear.html)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.   
When I add the code you gave, it writes today's date to the screen.    
I want to show the creation date of the related article.     

I keep the date data in the articles with the name field_haber_tarih
I edited the code as below, but nothing changed.  
  
<span class="search-result__date">  
    {{ content['#node'].field_haber_tarih|date('Y-m-d') }}  
</span>  
  
My Drupal knowledge is quite weak. What am I missing?